# Fragment in RecyclerView which is in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Can I create Fragment inside RecyclerView item. RecyclerView also placed in another Fragment.
I tried this code for creating Fragment:

```
  if(mDataSet[position].Repost.fromName!=""){
            val bundle= Bundle()
            bundle.putString("Value", data)
            bundle.putStringArrayList("list",ArrayList(lines))
            bundle.putInt("string",lines.indexOf(search))
            repostFragment.arguments=bundle
            val manager = supportFragmentManager
            val transaction= manager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.repost_fragment,repostFragment)
            transaction.commit()
        }
```

But supportFragmentManager highlights like uresolved reference

Comment: cause it should be called from within an activity, that's why. Pass context to wherever you're calling this

Answer (score 0):

> `supportFragmentManager` highlights like unresolved reference

`supportFragmentManager` is available only from `FragmentActivity`: [source](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity#getSupportFragmentManager()).

Use `parentFragmentManager` instead: [source](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getParentFragmentManager()).

Comment: how to get manager from recyclerview.onbindviewholder?

Comment: **You should not do this**, but if you really need this you can get context from `itemView.context`, check `if (itemView.context is FragmentActivity)` and cast it to `FragmentActivity`. And then you will be able to get `supportFragmentManager`. **Important**: all transactions should be done from `Fragment` or `Activity` directly. It is their responsibility. Sometimes such actions are managed by [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) or similar.

Comment: if it may be case of problems I better try something else

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
fragment.requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
```

or

```
fragment.parentFragmentManager
```

NOTE: If you want the added fragment's lifecycle is same as its parent, you could also use

```
fragment.childFragmentManager
```